# SQL-HR Schema, Retrieving the Dept.Names,managers and employees per dept

Tags: sql

Hello guys and thank you in advance for your time and help.
So I am trying to get a list of the Department names their manager name and the total number of employees per department.
My code so far looks like this:

```
select d.department_name,e.first_name,e.last_name
from employees e, departments d 
where e.department_id = d.department_id and d.manager_id=e.employee_id
group by d.department_name,e.first_name,e.last_name
order by d.department_name;
```

which produces the list of the manager per department,but I am still short of the count of employees per department. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the COUNT function. Try this:

```
select d.department_name,e.first_name,e.last_name,count(e.employee_id) as `TotalNoOfEmployees`
from employees e JOIN departments d 
ON e.department_id = d.department_id and d.manager_id=e.employee_id
group by d.department_name,e.first_name,e.last_name
order by d.department_name;
```

Also try not to use the old way of Joining the tables ie, comma separated JOINS.

Comment: Thank you  for the advice.I already tried the count function at that specific point and run the query but I get a  total number of one employee per department.In this case i think SQL-developer counts the number of the employee_id-manager that fulfills the d.manager_id=e.employee_id condition.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of experimentation I got it. Posting it in case somebody might find it useful someday:

```
select distinct d.department_name,
(select  e.first_name||', '||e.last_name from employees e 
 where d.department_id=e.department_id and 
 d.manager_id=e.employee_id)as "manager_name", 
 ( select count( employee_id ) from employees e
 where d.department_id=e.department_id ) as "total_no_of_employees"   
 from employees e
 join departments d on d.department_id=e.department_id
  order by d.department_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select emp.manager_id, mgr.first_name, mgr.last_name, dept.department_name, count(emp.employee_id)
from hr.employees emp
join hr.employees mgr
on emp.manager_id = mgr.employee_id
join hr.departments dept
on mgr.department_id = dept.department_id
group by emp.manager_id, mgr.first_name, mgr.last_name, dept.department_name
order by department_name
```